# A cron job with a URL parameter is not working in cpanel

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have added the following cron job [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) with a parameter in cpanel, but it is not working.

```
0 * * * * php http://www.example.com/cron.php?instance=0
```

After searching a lot I changed this as follows.

```
0 * * * * php /home/username/public_html/cron.php?instance=0
```

But this is also not working for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
0 * * * * php /home/username/public_html/cron.php?instance=0
```

Some of server can not read the cron job URL with a parameter. They read the parameter if you use parameter as follows.

```
0 * * * * php /home/username/public_html/cron.php instance=0
```

This works for me!

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
0 * * * * curl --silent --compressed http://www.mysite.com/cron.php?instance=0
```

Or.

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://www.mysite.com/cron.php?instance=0
```

I hope it helps somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/yourfilename.php
```

Comment: 0 * * * * php /home/username/public_html/cron.php instance=0 try this

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use quotes.

For example:

```
CURL "http://www.example.com/cron.php?instance=0"
```